# r - Repeat panels in histogram (panel as object?)

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

Is there a way to arbitrarily repeat panels in the histogram? Using iris as a minimal example:

```
data(iris)
histogram(~Sepal.Length|Species, data=iris,layout=c(3,1))
```

This output shows 3 panels: setosa, versicolor, and virginica in a row. Can I repeat some of them, e.g., setosa 2 times, versicolor 3 times, virginica 2 times, then a total of 7 panels in the row?

It sounds a unusual request! But I'd know a way to do it. Is it possible to make each panel an object, so that I can manipulate them??

Comment: Readers will low rep probably cannot see it, but @mnel posted what seemed to me to be a fairly compact modification that accomplished the task. I hope he only deleted it so he could undelete an improved version

Comment: @Dwin -- I will undelete when I can work out why my data isn't tracking across as I would plan.

Comment: maybe `update(myPlot[rep(1:3,c(2,3,2))], layout=c(7,1))`?

Comment: @baptiste Thanks. This exactly does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy using `index.cond`.

```
histogram(~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris, 
          index.cond = list(c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 2))))
```

[image: Imgur]